# stdout redirect changing output

Tags: c, unix

I have a program called `abc`.

When I run the following command:

```
$ ./abc < infile
```

I get the following output:

```
ijklm
```

However, when I run:

```
$ ./abc < infile > outfile
$ cat outfile
```

I am given this output:

```
ijkoo
```

Now, I'm assuming this is a bug with my program. However, regardless of what my program is doing, I do not know how this is possible.

**EDIT:**

Now that I know it is possible, I'm curious as to what it is in my program that is causing this.

There is a block inside a loop in my program that contains:

```
byte = ascii_to_byte(asciibyte);
putchar(byte);
```

byte is of type `char`.

Now if I change `putchar(byte)` to `printf("%c", byte)` all the output stays the same.

However, if I change it to `printf("%d", byte)`, then `$ ./abc < infile` outputs:

```
105106107111111
```

Which is the decimal representation of those ascii characters as they were in `outfile`. But it's not the decimal representation of the characters as they actually appeared when they just got sent to stdout. I don't understand why there could be this difference.

**EDIT #2:**

If I change the printing line to `printf("%c\n", byte)`, then `$ ./abc < infile` outputs:

```
i
j
k
o
o
```

This is consistent with what goes into outfile. Again, not sure what the difference is.

**EDIT #3**

I just tested this on a 32 bit machine, and the program works: `outputfile` contains `ijklm`. Wierd.

**EDIT #4**

Here is the main function:

```
int main()
{
    char asciibyte[8];
    char byte;

    int c; //Using int to avoid the EOF pitfall.
    long charcount = 0;

    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
        if(c != '0' && c != '1'){
            continue;
        }
        asciibyte[charcount % 8] = c;
        if(charcount % 8 == 7){
            /*Testing revealed that at this point asciibyte does contain
            what it should contain, eight ASCII ones and zeros representing
            a byte read in from stdin*/
            byte = ascii_to_byte(asciibyte);
            /*Print statements such as:
                printf("%d", byte);
                printf("%c\n", byte);
            reveal that the ascii_to_byte function works incorrectly on my
            64 bit machine. However these statements:
                putchar(byte);
                printf("%c", byte);
            make it appear as though the function operates as it should.
            EXCEPT if i redirect that output to a file.*/
            putchar(byte);
        }
        charcount++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the ascii_to_byte function:

```
char ascii_to_byte(char *asciibyte){
    char byte;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i){
        if(asciibyte[7-i] == '1'){
            byte = byte | (1 << i);
        }
    }
    return byte;
}
```

**FINAL EDIT**

I noticed that I should have initialized byte to 0x00. Problem solved. Why am I this retarded? I'll give answer points to whoever can explain specifically how this caused the problem.

Comment: is the output always the same? if you run ./abc a couple of times, do you get the same result?

Comment: Yes, the output is consistent over multiple trials.

Comment: what is the output of `./abc < infile | od -tx1`?

Comment: `0000000 69 6a 6b 6f 6f
0000005`

Comment: At this point, you need to start narrowing down the problem. Ideally, you want to get to a single page of code that still has the issue, that can be posted here. While trimming out stuff and replacing it with mockups, watch carefully for anything that might have side effects, or might overrun buffers.

Comment: @oadams: try to increase the warning level of your compiler and see it it "complains" about some thing relevant :)

Answer (score 3):

This sort of weird behaviour, which comes and goes according to seemingly unrelated changes, is probably indicative of your program reading from or writing to memory it shouldn't, and the behaviour changing as other parts of the code make different use of the stack and/or heap.

I would check your code carefully for badness such as buffer overruns, functions which return pointers to variables on the stack, etc.

Stepping through your code with a debugger may well be productive (or it could change the behaviour again if you're unlucky!).

There are a couple of interesting things you've seen:

1. How can the redirection of `stdout` possibly affect anything?  Perhaps because it causes the C library to behave a bit differently: a different buffering mode is used for the stream, depending on whether it is connected to a terminal device or not (see the [GNU libc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Buffering-Concepts.html#Buffering-Concepts), or [C99](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) §7.9.13 para. 7).
2. Why does changing `putchar(byte)` to `printf("%c", byte)` not change anything, when both `printf("%d", byte)` and `printf("%c\n", byte)` do change the behaviour?  Perhaps because the compiler automatically rewrites `printf("%c", byte)` to the more efficient `putchar(byte)` - vaguely recent versions of GCC normally do this, even when no optimisations are enabled - whereas `printf("%d", byte)` and `printf("%c\n", byte)` really will be compiled as calls to `printf()`.

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible - the program could check if it is writing to a terminal and write something different from what it would write when writing to a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `byte` is uninitialized, so **anything** may happen.

One of the things that may happen, is that `byte` "starts" at 0 and keeps its value from function call to function call (as if it was declared `static`).

```
in binary ...

   byte    |    c (bin)   |   byte | c
-----------+--------------+--------------
 00000000  | i (01101001) | 01101001 (i)
 01101001  | j (01101010) | 01101011 (k) * strange you get 'j', but anything can happen :)
 01101011  | k (01101011) | 01101011 (k)
 01101011  | l (01101100) | 01101111 (o)
 01101111  | m (01101101) | 01101111 (o)
```

Answer (score 0):

What Neil Butterworth says. The function is called [`isatty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/isatty.html).

```
if (isatty(STDOUT)) printf("I am printing to the terminal!\n");
```

Also, while testing stuff, you might have done:

```
$ ./abc < infile > infile
```

by accident. So, you might want to check quickly, that `infile` really contains the same data.

Comment: Yeah I've done this a bunch of times with different test input, and i's still wierd.